# unable to run copy command using docker file

Tags: copy, dockerfile

I am trying to run copy command in docker file but getting error as below :

RUN mkdir C:\RPS
COPY C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RpsSetup\MSI\6.5 C:\RPS
RUN Write-Host 'Installing RPS' ; \
    Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i', 'rps64.msi', '/quiet', '/norestart' -NoNewWindow -Wait

COPY C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RpsSetup\MSI\6.5 C:\RPS
failed to build: COPY failed: CreateFile \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder075489208\C:inetpubwwwrootRpsSetupMSI6.5: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I am fine with running .msi directly from path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RpsSetup\MSI\6.5\rps64.msi but when I try to achieve the same using command : RUN Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i', 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RpsSetup\MSI\6.5\rps64.msi', '/quiet', '/norestart' -NoNewWindow -Wait It throws error

Comment: Hello Team, I am still stuck here. Can someone please respond ?